# Can the WPF Datagrid control be made to behave like the WinForms DataGridControl in regard to column layout?

Tags: wpf, layout, datagrid

Basically, I'd like to make the WPF DataGrid control layout its columns exactly the way the WinForms DataGridView does

And more specifically, here is the behaviour I'm looking for:

- The grid control should take up the space it's given (i.e. however much space is available in its parent control for it to use).  Here I am referring just to the control, and not to the columns.
- The columns created (whether automatically or manually) may or may not take up all this space.
- If there is extra space left over after the columns are created, the last column should not be expanded to fill this space
- If there is extra space left over after the columns are created, an empty column with nothing in it should not be created to fill this extra space

From what I can tell, in WPF the last two bullet points seem to be mutually exclusive and you must choose one or the other.  Has anyone found a way to do both?  I've searched quite a bit and haven't found quite what I'm looking for, however all the posts I'm finding tend to be a couple years old so I'm hoping someone has figured this thing out by now.

EDIT: sa_ddam213, here's a quick xaml project I put together to test your suggestion.

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridFix.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridFix"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="data"
                    ObjectType="{x:Type local:TestObject}"
                    MethodName="GetTestData" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left"  ColumnWidth="Auto" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource data}}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And here's the code behind:

namespace DataGridFix
{
    public class TestObject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

```
    public static List<TestObject> GetTestData()
    {
        var items = new List<TestObject>();

        items.Add(new TestObject() { Id = 1, Name = "Joe" });
        items.Add(new TestObject() { Id = 2, Name = "Matt" });
        items.Add(new TestObject() { Id = 3, Name = "Hal" });

        return items;
    }
}
```

}

Really the only noteable thing I see from your suggestion is to set HorizontalAlignment to Left.  I did that, and tried setting the ColumnWidth to the various settings but had the same problem with each (except * of course... technically I can mess that one up to but I won't go into that).

If you use your mouse to expand any of the columns, and then decrease the column size then the empty filler column appears.  The only other difference I noted from your post was that you put your DataGrids in a StackPanel since you had more than one of them.  I tried that just for the heck of it but same result.  If you see any other difference between what I'm doing and what you suggested please let me know.

Comment: 'behavior', that is.  I'm not English (no offence English people).

Comment: so you want the grid to fill the parent but not make the columns auto fit and somehow not leave any blank space?? The whole reason for `Auto` with is to remove any blank space, I;m not sure how you can have both.

Comment: @sa_ddam213 Have you ever used the WinForms DataGridView control?  My initial guess as to why this concept is foreign to you is because you haven't.  If that's the case, then you may not find the behavior I described in the realm of your experience, but that doesn't mean that it doesn't make sense :)  And I'm just wondering if there's a work around to make the WPF DataGrid behave the same way the DataGridView does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to get the behavior you want, you probably have to modify the control template of the `DataGrid`.

Take a look at the code. I have gotten pretty close to the WinForms `DataGridView` look i think.

To remove the extra column you have to remove the filler column from the `DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter`. I have just commented it out. The rest is just the default template.

The other modification is to the template of the `DataGrid.`
By setting `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` on the `ScrollContentPresenter`, the rows no longer take up all the width of the control.

Those are the only 2 changes I have made to the default templates.

[image]

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter}">
                <Grid>
                    <!-- Remove this filler column -->
                    <!--<DataGridColumnHeader x:Name="PART_FillerColumnHeader" IsHitTestVisible="False" />-->
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <ScrollViewer Focusable="false" Name="DG_ScrollViewer">
                        <ScrollViewer.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Button Command="{x:Static DataGrid.SelectAllCommand}"
                                                    Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=CellsPanelHorizontalOffset}"
                                                    Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}, ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle}}"
                                                    Focusable="false"
                                                    Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=HeadersVisibility, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.All}}" />

                                    <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter Grid.Column="1" Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter"
                                                    Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=HeadersVisibility, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}}"/>

                                    <!-- Set HorizontalAlignment="Left" to have the rows only take up the width they need and not fill the entire width of the DataGrid -->
                                    <ScrollContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" />

                                    <ScrollBar Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                                                        Orientation="Vertical"
                                                        Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                                                        ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                                                        Value="{Binding Path=VerticalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                        Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"/>

                                    <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset}"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ScrollBar Grid.Column="1"
                                                    Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                                                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                                                    Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                                                    ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                                                    Value="{Binding Path=HorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                    Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ScrollViewer.Template>
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**UPDATE**
It does indeed look like there is a difference between .NET 4 and .NET 4.5.
I develop on a Windows 8 machine with Visual Studio 2012, so as a test I tried targeting .NET 4 to see if I could replicate the wrong behavior. But it still worked fine.

To be sure, I tried running the app on a different machine with only .NET 4 installed, and here the empty rows showed up when making a column bigger and then smaller again.

The issue seems to be that the `DataGridRows` are not behaving properly. When running on a machine with only .NET 4 installed, they keep their current size when making the column smaller. On .NET 4.5 they resize as expected.

The new solution to get the behavior you need, is actually much simpler than the previous one.

By simply setting the `HorizontalAlignment` on the `DataGridRows` to `left`, and removing the filler column, it works on both .NET 4 and .NET 4.5. And there is no longer a need to replace the entire template of the `DataGrid`.

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
</Style>
<Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter}">
                <Grid>
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Regardless of what form the final solution takes, it'll likely take the form of retooling the control template like this. I heartily recommend a tool like Blend or XamlPad for any control template tweaking.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I'll try this out soon and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Ok, this is really close.  The only thing I noticed that wasn't quite right is that if I expand a column and then make it smaller again then that empty column shows up again (except without a column header).  Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Hi - I can't seem to get that behavior in my example. My DataGrid is just bound to a array of simple objects and I get the same behavior regardless of whether AutoGenerateColumns is true or false. Maybe you have set some other properties on the DataGrid which causes this behavior?

Comment: Hmm... sa_ddam213 is also talking as if he's not having the same issue.  To test your answer, I simply copy/pasted your code into the Window.Resources area of the code you can see in the edit I just made to my post.  Is there anything else I should do?  If you guys aren't experiencing the same behavior it makes me wonder whether I'm not communicating the issue I'm having very well or if you guys are maybe using Visual Studio 2012 and possibly there's a difference between it and the 2010 version I'm using.

Comment: Or, rather a difference between net 4.0 and 4.5 is what I should have said.

Comment: Yeah, apparently something has changed in .NET 4.5. I have updated my answer to fix the issue in .NET 4.

Answer (score 5):

There ar plenty of layout options for Columns in WPF, its just a matter of choosing what you want to be displayed.

- Pixel
- SizeToCells
- SizeToHeader
- Auto
- Proportional(*)

And if you set the `HorizontalAlignment` to `Left` the `DataGrid` will resize to fit its contents based on the `ColumnWidth` you picked.

Here is a example of some of the avaliable column settings

```
   <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left"  ColumnWidth="100" Height="64" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=GridItems}" />
        <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left"  ColumnWidth="SizeToCells" Height="64" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=GridItems}" />
        <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left"  ColumnWidth="SizeToHeader" Height="64" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=GridItems}" />
        <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left"  ColumnWidth="Auto" Height="64" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=GridItems}" />
        <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left"  ColumnWidth="*" Height="64" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=GridItems}" />
    </StackPanel>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but none of these 'out of the box' solutions do quite what I described.  In the picture above, the first 4 examples violate the last stipulation I wrote.  The last one is the closest, but if you change the window size then the column sizes will change with it which violates the 3rd stipulation I wrote (although in this case intead of just the last column expanding it would be all the columns expanding to fill in the empty space)

Comment: If it helps, imagine custom user control with a red background that contains a single text box.  When the user control is expanded, the red background should expand with it, but the text box should remain the same size.  That's more or less the bahavior I'm after.

Comment: @BrandonMoore this here was an excellent answer. To prevent the DataGrid from sizing with the parent simply set its Width to a predetermined value, so you can see your red background. This looks more like a confused UI design than a good question if the examples above didn't answer it. One thing to leave behind when using WPF is WinForms - don't try to match their behavior, embrace what WPF has to offer - it is a lot more than WinForms

Comment: Updated answer with the `HorizontalAlignment` set as I think this is what you are after to match Winform behaviour

Comment: @StenPetrov Contrary to what you might think, I didn't ask for help in understanding why my question is dumb and how I should just accept out of the box WPF behavior as superior to whatever I might prefer.  I don't want a stupid empty column appended to the end of my DataGrid and this is the first control I've *ever* seen that does that so it's kind of silly for you to suggest that this aspect of how these controls have behaved for the last 20 years is 'confused'.

Comment: @sa_ddam213 Thanks, I'll try your updated answer soon and let you know what happens.

Comment: @sa_ddam213 Although this solution isn't exactly what I had in mind, it would be acceptable if one more modification could be made to it.  Instead of getting rid of the filler column like Peter Hansen's solution attempts to do, your solution just sizes the grid to the exact size of the columns so no there is no extra space between the last column and the end of the control.  However, if I expand a column and then make it smaller the control doesn't resize itself to get smaller again which makes the filler column appear.  Can you do anything about that?

Comment: Could you post a small Xaml example of that behaviour as I can't get the filler column to appear if I resize expand a column. It sounds like its the container that is holding the grid is causing the behaviour not the grid control itself.

Comment: @sa_ddam213 Just added it.  Sorry, I would have put it up earlier but SO didn't put one of those notification thingies in my inbox so I just saw your comment.

Comment: Sorry I still cannot replicate the behaviour you're describing, I can't get a filler column to appear even with your sample code. If you compile my sample does the same thing happen?

Comment: It seems the difference in behavior we're experiencing may be due using different versions of the net framework (I'm on 4.0).  Peter was able to come up with a solution that worked for me, but thanks a ton for your assistance.  +1